# How to multiply in Excel using a fraction

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am looking to multiply a fraction (Betting Odd) by a whole number (Currency amount) for a betting spreadsheet I am creating for friends, and cannot find the answer anywhere in excel 2016.

Example: 22/1 x £5.00

Looking for the formula to multiply the £5 by 21 but also needs to add the stake (£5) back on, to return the proper answer of £110 return.

Comment: fractions are just a way to represent a division. divide then multiply.

Comment: The `£` is just formatting.  Use the proper number format on the cell in which the output is placed.

Comment: Just multiply and add:  `theBet * theOdds + theBet`  where `theOdds` and `theBet` are cell references containing the obvious.  Did you try it and something went wrong?  If so, edit your question to show exactly what you did, and what the problem was.

Comment: Also, how to come up with `110` as the proper answer when `theOdds * theBet`-->`110` with out adding back `theBet`

Comment: Hi Ron Rosenfield, what is happening is that when A1 formatted to "currency" with 2 decimal points contains the "£5" bet, and cell A2 formatted to "Fraction" contains "21/1" the odds. Then when I put the following formula into cell A3 =(A1)*(A2)+(A1) I get a massive number for an answer!

Comment: I'm sure there must be a way to do it. I pretty good at excel formula myself, as I'm a logic thinker. But this one has got me stumped a bit formatting wise. Was looking for someone who has maybe solved this previously, or some whizz that can work it out. Not finding help much use in excel.

Comment: I cannot reproduce what you are getting. BUT, are you certain the fraction cell is really formatted as a fraction?  If you are getting a very large number, I suspect it is really formatted as `d/m` (or the equivalent in your language) and that your windows regional settings are `DMY`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the correct answer by putting:
=(5)*(21)+(5) [I tested it in Excel to be sure]
and if these amount are cells you can just replace the numbers within the parenthesis with links to the cells.

Excel should be able to work out any fraction and multiplication by using / and *

Comment: Thank you for your answer eatonm, I can do what you say easily enough with my knowledge. But what I need is for the cells to calculate the fraction in one cell i.e. 22/1 (the odds) x £5.00 (the bet). The problem is that the odds are shown in the cell as a fraction, not a whole number. Any idea on how to make it do the calculation in that manner? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try working with the odds as text:

`=A1*VALUE(LEFT(A2,FIND("/",A2)-1))/VALUE(RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND("/",A2)))`

Comment: Not seeing how that works out.
Just tried it on 3 cells and only getting "#VALUE" returned with that formula.
I'm amazed that it is so difficult for excel to calculate a fraction in this manner. 
My three cell calculation is: A1 is "£5" (bet) formatted to currency, A2 is "10/1" (the odds) formatted to fraction, so looking for A3 to hold the formula and display the answer.

Comment: When you select A2, what is displayed in the formula bar?